# Error: Route.delete() requires a callback function but got a [object Undefined]

Tags: node.js, mongodb

''' in user.controller i put this method''''

```
    exports.delete= (req, res) => {
    User.findByIdAndRemove(req.params.id)
    .then((user) => {
      if (!user) {
        return res.status(404).send({
          message: "User not found ",
        });
      }
      res.send({ message: "User deleted successfully!" });
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      return res.status(500).send({
        message: "Could not delete user ",
      });
    });
};
}
```

''' and in user.routes i put this code even when i use the put or get this error appear '''

```
 const controller = require("../controllers/user.controller");
    module.exports = function(app) {
      app.use(function(req, res, next) {
        res.header(
          "Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
          "x-access-token, Origin, Content-Type, Accept"
        );
        next();
      }); 
    
      app.delete("/api/users/Delete/:id", controller.delete);
}
```

Comment: Do a `console.log(controller.delete)` and see what that is in `user.routes` where you get the error.  Apparently, it's not what you think it is which probably means there's something wrong with your exports of perhaps you have a circular `require()`.

Comment: it shows [undefined]

Comment: So, it's pretty clear your import or export isn't working right.  You don't show all of that code here for us to see.

Comment: i solved the issue thank you so much for your help

Answer (score 0):

Since `controller.delete` is `undefined`, there is apparently a problem with either your `require()` statements or your `exports` within the module since the `.delete` method is not present on the module you are expecting it to be.  Since you don't show all the related code for how everything is imported and exported, we can't help more specifically than that.

Comment: this error appear again this is a Link of the complete code  https://github.com/yassmine817/AppResto/tree/master          please i need help

Comment: @yass-  In the code in your repository, it shows `app.delete("/api/users/Delete/:id", console.log(controller.delete));`.  That is definitely wrong.  Remove the `console.log()`.

Comment: when i removed it it shows this error       """"SyntaxError: Unexpected token
 in JSON at position 28
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)"""""

Comment: @yass - We could only help with that error if you showed the exact incoming request that causes it, including the method, path, headers, query parameters and JSON body that triggers the error.